# Inner SQL statement while inserting values in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called addresses_users which maps address to the users. Table structure is.

```
------------------------------------------
id  | projectid   | crmconfigid  | order     |
------------------------------------------
1   |    1        |    1         |   1       |
------------------------------------------
2   |    2        |    1         |   3       |
------------------------------------------
3   |    3        |    1         |   2       |
------------------------------------------
```

This is the table structure with some existing data, what I want to do is, I want to update priority of the address to the MAX(order)+1 of the user while inserting new record.

I am trying a sql

`INSERT INTO projectcrm VALUES (1,1, (SELECT MAX(order)+1 FROM projectcrm WHERE projectid = 1));`

For example :

`INSERT INTO projectcrm SELECT 1, 1, MAX(order) FROM projectcrm WHERE projectid = 1` is not working for me.`

Giving error :
Error Code: 1136
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Maybe it does not count MAX(order) as a column.

Comment: `INSERT INTO addresses_users SELECT 1, 1, MAX(priority) FROM addresses_users WHERE user_id = 1`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Sorry to say, but your solution is not working for me and now that you have already marked it as `duplicate` nobody can answer it. :/

Comment: No worries, I reopened, but it should have worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
INSERT INTO addresses_users (projectid, crmconfigid, order)
SELECT 1, 1, MAX(order) + 1
FROM addresses_users
WHERE projectid = 1
```

Comment: It says `Error Code: 1048
Column 'order' cannot be null`

Comment: Then you gave us the wrong table structure.  Update your question with the real information.

Comment: Though its just name, i will update my question with real information.

Comment: I updated my answer.  This is the last update I will make.  Follow the duplicate link if you need more help.